# Turn on computer with wireless keyboard

Tags: keyboard, motherboard, power-management, wireless-keyboard

I have a PC connected to my TV that I like to use from the sofa. I have a wireless keyboard (Logitech K400, [this one](http://www.logitech.com/en-roeu/product/wireless-touch-keyboard-k400r)) for the purpose. I would like to be able to turn the PC on (as opposite to just bring it back from suspension, etc.) using the wireless keyboard. My motherboard is Gigabyte (GA-B85M-HD3, [this one](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4568#ov)). Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: From the manual it doesn't look like you can wake it with anything other than a plugged in PS2 keyboard or mouse, or a timeed event.  Perhaps you could rig something that would close a switched plugged into the PS2 port remotely.

Comment: Is your PC connected to a router with an ethernet cable??

Comment: @shub No, unfortunately I only have a wifi card for connecting to the internet, although I have a spare router I could use.

Comment: @Miguel If you had it connected to a router, you could use Wake-On-Lan, looking at your specs, your motherboard supports it. You could then use something like your phone, download something like Fing and wake-on-lan your computer